# Am I allowed to ask interior decorating questions on this site?

Tags: discussion

Am I allowed to ask interior decorating questions on this site? Or is there a sub site that deals only with decorating?

Comment: The **how** of decorating is OK, e.g. there are lots of questions about [tag:painting]; the **what** is not OK, e.g. "what color should I paint my ..?".

Answer (score 4):

There is no SE site I'm aware of that deals with decorating advice. It's too subjective for a Q&A format, e.g. no correct answers, only opinions. As Niall C says, how to implement your selected decoration is usually ok (how do I paint this, how can I hang that, etc), but how should you decorate is off topic (how should I layout this room, what color looks best, etc).